# Can I pluck the extra hair between the eyebrows and forehead?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, human-body

My forehead is small and the eyebrows have grown in such a way that they meet the edges of my forehead and my eyebrows look very thick. I don't want to make it thin, but can I pluck this extra hair which is growing in between the eyebrows and forehead?

Answer (score 1):

According to Islamqa, yes it is permissible to remove the hair between the eyebrows

> b)    The Committee was asked:
>   What is the Islamic ruling on plucking the hair between the eyebrows?
>   They replied:
>   It is permissible to pluck it, because it is not part of the eyebrows.
>   (Fataawa al-Lajnah al-Daa’imah, 5/197)

I think you should read the full article since it is more complete and it talks about hair that is obligatory to get rid of, hair that is prohibited from getting rid of, and hair that is permissible to get rid of. http://Islamqa.info/en/9037